# Is Interlock.Add + Cast faster than single lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, interlocked

I'm looking for the better way to do `Interlocked.Add(ref double, double)`.

**First Way, with `Interlocked.Add(ref long, long)` and some casting**

On a parallel loop:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref ltotalUpSeconds,  (long) (av.totalUpSeconds * 1000));
```

Then outside the loop

```
totalUpSeconds =  ltotalUpSeconds/1000D;
```

**Second way, with a lock** :

```
lock (parallelocker)
{
    totalUpSeconds += av.TotaUpSeconds;
}
```

I use to hear that `lock` is slower than `Interlocked`. But is the loose of performance worths the readability of the lock ?

**NB : I don't mind about loosing precision**.

Comment: Why not test it out yourself?

Comment: @Alex : it's "my" way to keep 2 decimals precision when casting double to long.

Comment: A full `lock` is quite slow. Probably better to use the `SpinLock`... Still the cast would be much faster.

Comment: "Faster" is of no concern, this is just plain wrong.  You now have two variables, one of which you do not update atomically.  So non-zero odds that the ltotalUpSeconds you use in the division is stale, the same effect as not using Interlocked.  Just much harder to debug since it happens less frequently.  If it has to be *double* then you'll have to take the lock. If it has to be micro-optimized then just call it *totalUpMilliseconds*.

Comment: I'm taking account everything you said so I'm gonna make a SpinLock with double only. Thanks all.